# Python client server dilemma

Tags: python

I'm trying to implement a project, where the python code will be written on web-browser and then executed in a remote server. 
The arch is Javascript --> Java --> python

The python code will be sent to java using web sockets, which is connected to a python server using a TCP/IP socket. The script needs to be read line by line from the socket using readLine and executed.
It would be great if someone can tell me how to run python commands within a python script. Is there a better way to do it, like for example, save it as a file and run the the entire script and send the output back to Java?

For example, I want to execute the following from the socket as I read it using readLine...

```
import pylab as pl 
import numpy as np
y = randn(100)
pl.plot(y)
pl.savefig('foo.png', bbox_inches='tight)
```

I have written the TCP/IP socket which gets the data from the java client

Any help here would be appreciated.

Comment: What code have you tried so far?

Comment: The answer really depends on the details, e.g. do you want to execute all of Python or just a subset of the language, do you need to secure execution or the remote server is a one-time isolated VM etc.

Comment: What do you mean by `run python commands within a python script`? What is a `python command`?

Comment: @ MarkyPython, @ Richard Jones...I've updated my question with the details

Comment: @Sergei Lebedev, I want to execute the entire python code...The remote server is a one time isolated VM

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just put it in a variable as a string and use exec:

```
tmp_str = '''
print "Hello World!"
print "another hello world!"
         '''

exec tmp_str
```